# regex to match child mount points

Tags: regex, bash

I am writing bash script for checking that "child mounts" doesn't exits before "parent mounts" on fstab

i.e: if I have the following mounts on fstab:

good: parent mount point first

```
/Application
/Application/home
```

bad: child mount point first

```
/Application/home
/Application/
```

So I want to loop all the mount points in fstab and compare the match to a regex that will check regex of "mount point" +/ to catch all child mount points. In this case I want to catch any mount point that have /application/ mount point.

I am trying

```
for child in $MATCH;do
  if [[ "$child" =~ [/\/application\//] ]];then
    echo "$child has child mounts before it"
  fi
done
```

but it catches more matches than expected. Please help me with the correct regex.

Comment: I don't see a regex problem, so much as a number of general logic errors. You are not showing how MATCH is being set so it is rather impossible to diagnose the problem in any detail.

Comment: The superfluous square brackets in your regex are an obvious problem, though. The [`regex` tag wiki](//stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) has a short section about this specific error.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Awk for this.

```
awk '/\/Application\// { child=1; next }
    /\/Application/ { if (child) {
        print FILENAME ": error: child mount precedes application mount"
        exit(1)
    }
    app=1 }
    END { if (! child || ! app) {
       print FILENAME ": missing mount(s)"
        exit(2)
    }' /etc/fstab
```

Are you really sure the mount point order in `fstab` is actually significant, though?

Comment: I'm running Archlinux with an fstab in which / appears after /boot.

Answer (score 0):

Given a file with all the mount points from /etc/fstab, separated by a new-line, like this one for example:

```
/Application/home
/Application/
```

you can execute the following

`grep -n '/Application/' mount_points_file | sort -k2 -t\:`

which will output:

```
2:/Application/
1:/Application/home
```

From this step you can see that */Application/* appears on line number 2, while its child */Application/home* appears on line number 1, which you define as a bad order.

Actually `sort`'s `-c` option can detect a disorder and inform you about it in *stderr*:

`grep -n '/Application/' mount_points_file | sort -t\: -k2 | sort -c -t\: -k1n`

Will output :

`sort: -:2: disorder: 1:/Application/home`

But I think it will stop on the first disordered entry.

Aside: I don't think `/etc/fstab`'s order matter.
I run Archlinux with an fstab in which I have */boot* before */*.