# bash: set exit status without breaking loop?

Tags: bash

I am writing bash script to check the `fstab` structure.

In a `for` loop, I have placed a `return` statement to use the exit code later in the script, but it seems that the `return` statement is breaking the loop after printing the first requested output

How can I assign a return code of 1 without breaking the loop so I will get all the results and not just the first?

```
for i in $(printf  "$child"|awk '/'$new_mounts'/'); do

    chid_count=$(printf  "$child"|awk '/'$new_mounts'/'|wc -l)

    if [[ $chid_count -ge 1 ]]; then
        echo -e "\e[96mfstab order check failed: there are child mounts before parent mount:\e[0m"
        echo -e "\e[31mError: \e[0m "$child"\e[31m  mount point, comes  before \e[0m $mounts \e[31m on fstab\e[0m"
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
done
```

Comment: ...btw, `'/'$new_mounts'/'` is very, very wrong -- it string-splits the contents of `new_mounts` rather than passing it to awk as part of a single argument. `"/$new_mounts/"` would be an improvement. Consider passing your code through http://shellcheck.net/, and reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes closely.

Comment: ...similarly, any shell where `echo -e` does anything other than print `-e` on its output is out of compliance with the POSIX sh standard -- see the POSIX spec for echo at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html. Consider using printf instead, which allows a standards-compliant, portable tool for comparable tasks.

Comment: Tempted to flag as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533501/regex-to-match-child-mount-points but I'll just repeat what I wrote in my answer there: use Awk.

Comment: @tripleee, ...that is, indeed, a *very* on-point answer for the larger problem (as opposed to the immediate language-level question).

Comment: @Max_il, ...btw, also, `for i in $(...)` is actually not the best tool for the job when your goal is to iterate over lines of output. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor, and/or http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 (for something with a focus on the best-practice approach).

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation for the language, immediately returning is what return is **supposed** to do. That's not unique to shell -- I actually can't think of a single language with a `return` construct where it *doesn't* behave this way.

If you want to set a value to be used as a return value later, use a variable:

```
yourfunc() {
  local retval=0

  for i in ...; do
    (( child_count >= 1 )) && retval=1
  done

  return "$retval"
}
```

Comment: Haskell's `return` doesn't :)

Comment: @chepner, Haskell guarantees order of operation between statements at all? That's not as purely functional as I'd expect. :)